# How to manage version controlled Django migrations as a team?

Tags: django, git, django-migrations, django-3.0

We're a small team of developers working on a version-controlled Django 3 project. We are worried about utilizing migrations and the possibility of overwriting one another's migration files.

Options we've considered:

- Using the `--name` / `-n` option of `makemigrations` to have a naming convention, but that seems cumbersome
- [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#version-control) mentions tools for version control, but I don't see much on the specifics on it.

How do other teams handle this?

Comment: Relevant threads: (1) [Is it really important to save django's migrations in a version control system? (`dev.to`)](https://dev.to/simo97/is-it-really-important-to-save-djangos-migrations-in-a-version-control-system--5d03); (2) [How do you guys manage git + migrations? (`reddit`)](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/msm26e/how_do_you_guys_manage_git_migrations/)

Answer (score 4):

Using version control (git, etc.) will solve your problem.

Just make sure the developers work on a branch rather than directly on master. This way, the migrations will be visible, and if there's a conflict, git will let you know when you try to merge to your master branch. It's even more obvious if you're using GitHub as you can see the conflicts in the UI for the pull request.

The only problem you will have here is if two migrations are generated in the same app in two PRs. The one that gets merged into master last will cause a problem as there will be multiple leaf nodes, but this can be solved easily with `./manage.py makemigrations --merge`, and ideally you should run `./manage.py makemigrations --check` to see if there are problems before merging stuff - in continuous integration, for exaple.

Comment: Thank you! We're trying to avoid migrations generated on separate branches that would end up auto-generating the same name.

Comment: It doesn't happen. The only way this can happen is if there is _only one_ change. Otherwise, Django will use the timestamp, so two devs would have to generate them at the same minute. If there is only one change, it uses the name of the field or model. In practice I've never seen this happen, usually devs are not working on the same model at once, but even if it does, you'll get a merge conflict in git, and at this point you'll know you need to generate a new migration and give it a unique name on one of the branches.

Comment: You know... I don’t think I’ve ever noticed that! Thank you!